# SQL Server JOIN adds results?

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a table which basically contains a `Person_ID, Action, TimeStamp` and using Microsoft ReportBuilder I have a report which tables each Person and the COUNT for their Actions.

```
Person     Action X       ActionY
1             3              5
2             0              4
```

Now I need to filter the results to only show people in a certain group which is defined by another table containing Person_ID, Group_ID.

When I do a JOIN and filter results based on the Group_ID = x the counts are very high, although it does filter correctly.

I run the query manually in SQL Server Manager and it is returning the same row multiple times?

EDIT:

My current SQL is

```
select t1.personid, t1.action, t2.personid, t2.groupid 
from t1 
inner join t2 on t1.personid = t2.personid 
where t2.groupid = 1
```

This returns each line multiple times, forgetting the count part as this is in the report builder I would like to understand why the same row is returned multiple times as this is what breaks the report.

Comment: could you show some example data?  ie, some stuff from table 1, some stuff from table 2, what you want and what you're getting?

Comment: Using SELECT DISTINCT works but I still don't understand what causes the query to return the same rows multiple times?  It must be to do with the JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a DISTINCT

SO..

```
SELECT PersonID, ActionX = COUNT(distinct varname), ActionY = SUM(distint varname)
FROM tblName1 a
INNER JOIN tblName2 b ON a.PersonID = b.PersonID
WHERE b.Group_ID = 'groupvar'
```

Comment: I used SELECT DISTINCT ... and now it works.  Is there a reason why the original query caused the same rows to be returned multiple times?  The COUNT part is all done by the report builder, there is one column Action which can contain Action X, Action Y, Action Z and the report produces a matrix.

Comment: Yeh the reason is because you must have some Data that has joins to multiple entries in your other table, so if you actually did a SELECT * you would notice everything, except for a few or 1 column was different. When you are doing your SUM are you GROUPING By PersonID. It might be useful in times like this to use a SubQuery to retrieve your joined DataSet and then do your Group By afterwards. Can also be faster.